# Why doesn't my manual RSA key exchange example work?

Tags: tls, rsa, key-exchange, asymmetric

I'm trying to "manually" compute  how the *premaster_secret* is computed using the RSA key exchange in TLS 1.2, but can't manage to make numbers meet. I am using Scapy SSL to generate a TLS session:

- I retrieve the *e* and *n* parameters from the first certificate's pubKey (Certificate message)
- I retrieve the *premaster_secret* from Scapy
- I compute (*premaster_secret<sup>e</sup> mod n*)
- I compare this result to the Encrypted Premaster sent in the Client Key Exchange message, but it is never the same

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using [unpadded "textbook RSA" vs. actual padded RSA.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49047/is-the-standard-scheme-of-rsa-cca-and-cpa-secure/49053#49053)

Comment: Yes, pkcs#1 v1.5

Comment: That's indeed what I was missing. I'm almost there. It works for a site such as www.wikipedia.org but not www.google.com - even though I am using its certificate to get the RSA public key.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the responses I was able to get it working. Here is some Python pseudo-code which explains the algorithm actually used by TLS 1.2:

```
# Come up with a random premaster_secret
# It needs to start with the TLS version (0x0303)
premaster_secret = '\x03\x03' + os.urandom(46)

# Retrieve the RSA parameters from the certificate public key
RSA_n = ...
RSA_e = ...

# Encodes premaster_secret using PKCS#1 v1.5
premaster_secret = '\x00\x02' + '\x12' * (256 - 3 - len(premaster_secret)) + '\x00' + premaster_secret

# Converts the result into a number and encrypts it
premaster_secret_nb = int(binascii.hexlify(premaster_secret), 16)
encrypted_premaster_secret = pow(premaster_secret_nb, RSA_e, RSA_n)
```